# How do you make a code that print numbers between N and M in C

Tags: c

I need to make a code that have the output of 1 to 10 when you input the number 1 and 10, but also have the output of 10 to 19 when you input the number 10 and 10.

I've tried the following :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int N;
    int M;

    scanf ("%d %d", &N, &M);
    
    for (int i = N ; i <= M ; i ++)
    while (N <= M) {
    printf ("%d\n", N ++);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but when I put 10 and 10, the output is also 10.
Thanks for your answer in advance, I only recently started learning and I'm already stuck.

Comment: when you enter 10 and 10 it will print from 10 to 19 or 11 to 20 ??

Comment: It should be 10 to 19

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. There's no such thing as C/C++. You should select only one of the language tags, since different languages have different solutions.

Comment: Ah, it should be C if that's the case

Comment: If you have made a mistake, then [edit] the post

Comment: you said you have to print number between min and max. So, how 10 and 10 are min and max if it could be then why it should print from 10-19. I am confused that it is specific for just 10 and 10?

Comment: it's not necessarily min and max, it's supposed to be two numbers input by the user, which is the N and M. sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ( int i = N; i < ( N + M ); i++ )
    printf( "%d\n" , i )
```

Just a loop from the bottom number, to the max. From your description, I assume the max is N + M.

Alternatively, you can loop fro `0` to `M`, but do addition in the output to get the min back in.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    printf( "%d\n" , i + N )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, both worked. I feel so dumb having to ask this basic question, thanks again.